# Can't publish .net core web api on local iis

Tags: c#, .net, iis, asp.net-core-webapi

I made a .net core web API project. My project has 3 layers. The first and second layers are .net core class library and the third layer is .net core web API.

When I start the web layer in Visual Studio with iis express no problem I can work with my web services but I want to publish it on my localhost it doesn't work.

I followed this tutorial: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZZfRlBMHds8 and when I try it with my project it doesn't work.

What should I do?

I also tried an empty web API project but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Does it work if you run the Kestrel web server?

Comment: i dont know how can i work with kestrel

Comment: .net core web projects have a built in web server called Kestrel.  At the top of Visual Studio, under the menu items, you can see a drop down with Debug, one with the name of your project and another one with a simplfied name of your project. If you click this 3rd on, you will drop down a menu that shows the possible ways of running your web site.  One will be IIS Express, one will be the name of your project.  This one is the Kestral one.

Answer (score 1):

I would make sure you have he IIS_IUSR permission for the directory the the WebApi is located in. Then, I would open the solution in VS as the administrator and right click the WebApi project and select Publish. This will open the configuration part of publishing your WebApi and you can set your settings here. Make sure you can connect to your IIS site you wish to publish to and save your settings. Then stop IIS, publish, then restart IIS. Hope this helps.

Comment: my folder located in inetpub/wwwroot/myprojectname

Comment: i can publish my files no problem

Comment: What is the error you get when you navigate to the localhost path from a browser (localhost/nameOfSite/api/resource)?